# I am looking for monitor and mouse calibration i/e changing the x / y positioning of them

Tags: mouse, monitor

I've just installed Ubuntu and am new to Linux.  My monitor is slightly offset; I can see the edge of the icons on the left edge of the screen on the right side of the screen, the top of the screen is a little low with a 1/4 inch gray bar, and I can't see the bottom scroll bar on Firefox, so the screen needs to be shifted a little to the right and a little to the top.  My mouse is also off center, rather than pointing with the tip of the arrow, I have to use the bottom middle of the pointer, which makes it hard to click on items, the same problem existed in the installation, but I figured I could fix it in system tools.  As far as the mouse, in Windows I would go to system setting / mouse / calibrate mouse, click on the center of the little box, and that would be it, similar to calibrating a flight stick.  I used the horizontal / vertical positioning on the monitor itself, and the edge of the screen / bottom scrollbar still didn't appear.  I have an old e-machines T3265 comp, and an emachines 500g LCD monitor. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try resizing your monitor in your personal settings.  If that doesn't work, just mess with your display settings.  You could also try connecting your laptop to different sized monitors while changing the resolution.  I had a similar problem, but my screen wasn't shifted.